# vim command to go to the start of a C function

Tags: vim

Is there a command to jump to the start of a C function . 
While in the body of a function , I would want to jump to the start of the function to see the function name.

Answer (score 4):

Also check out the `[m` command.

Answer (score 3):

Use `[{`.

That should get you to the opening brace.

Comment: @Reuben.L :I tried this and it takes me to the start of a block not a c function. If there are a bunch of nested ifs inside the function then using [{ does not help much. In emacs C-M-h helps with navigating to the start of a C function. I'm trying to find a vim equivalent for the same.

Comment: @Derek's answer might help then.

Answer (score 1):

I use `[[`, no matter how deep you are inside such function.
Use `]]` to go to next starting block function.